# Username not clickable on list of closers

Tags: support, closed-questions, users

Here is an example which shows a list of closers, but one which is not clickable: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10135685/1927206

User brian d foy has edited the question, provided an answer, and participated in the close.

brian d foy's user-profile is clickable from the edit on the question, from his answer, but not on the list of users effecting the close. I've not seen this before, but now this is the second one I've located for brian d foy.

Just wondering what that signifies. It not the only example for this same user.

Comment: I wonder if he voted to close and then retracted and somehow that still counted to adding his name to the close banner.

Comment: And that's why I normally don't try to guess at these things...

Comment: I read 'Username not clickable on list of losers' ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you look at the [PostHistoryTable](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/336099?opt.textResults=true) for that post you'll find for PostHistoryTypeid = 10 (close) the following value in the `text` column, representing all users that close voted:

```
{"Voters":[
   {"Id":23897,"DisplayName":"Michael Petrotta"},
   {"Id":8817,"DisplayName":"brian d foy"},
   {"Id":46395,"DisplayName":"daxim"},
   {"Id":106224,"DisplayName":"BoltClock's a Unicorn"}
]}
```

As you can see *brian d foy* had an id of 8817.

The user [brian d foy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2766176/brian-d-foy) has an userid of 2766176.

I suspect an account merge here (comfirmed by @JonClements) or a doppelgänger.

The wayback machine proves that [brian d foy](https://web.archive.org/web/20081217112133/https://stackoverflow.com/users/8817?) had id 8817 earlier (thanks @Hans)

Comment: Your former suspicion is correct - merges tended to sometimes do funny things historically :)

Comment: @JonClements: Well, do SE account merges still leave such wonderful artifacts, or is that corrected?

Comment: User 8817 used to be [brian d foy](https://web.archive.org/web/20081217112133/http://stackoverflow.com/users/8817?).

Comment: He lost his nice user ID. D: